# has_many and belongs_to assertion in MiniTest using Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I use Mongoid as database and I have two models like below. I couldn't assert has_many and belongs_to relationship. What can I assert this relations in MiniTest.

**Event.rb**

```
class Event
  include Schizo::Data
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  field :start_at
  field :finish_at
  field :status
  field :location

  has_many :participations
end
```

**Participation.rb**

```
class Participation
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :participant

end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I test `has_many` associations in Rails with Minitest and it should work for you as well. Put this in your model test file for `Event`:

```rb
  test 'contains a has_many relationship to participations' do
    expected = [
      :participations
    ].sort

    actual = Event.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).map(&:name).sort

    assert_equal(expected, actual)
  end
```

This is how I test `belongs_to` associations in Rails with Minitest and it should work for you as well. Put this in your model test file for `Participation`:

```rb
  test 'contains a belongs_to relationship to some models' do
    expected = [
      :event,
      :participant
    ].sort

    actual = Participation.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name).sort

    assert_equal(expected, actual)
  end
```

FYI: This should work regardless of database implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `mongoid-minitest` gem for that. See details [here](https://github.com/frodsan/mongoid-minitest#association-matchers)

Your specs will look like the following then:

```
describe Event do
  subject { Event }

  it { must have_many(:participations) }
end

describe Participation do
  subject { Participation }

  it { must belong_to(:participations) }
end
```